# Как с помощью openpyxl скопировать столбец из одной книги в другую

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Как скопировать данные из одного столбца excel книги в др книгу с помощью openpyxl?

Comment: https://yagisanatode.com/2017/11/18/copy-and-paste-ranges-in-excel-with-openpyxl-and-python-3/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44926058/2511795